# NodeJS Tests - exposing app

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I'm testing my NodeJS application with supertest. At the end of my app.js I expose my app, so I can use it within the test.js.

```
///////////////////
// https options
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("./private/keys/Server.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./private/certs/Server.crt"),
    ca: fs.readFileSync("./private/ca/CA.crt"),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

///////////////////
// start https server
var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(app.get("port"), function(){
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

exports = module.exports = server;
```

When I require my server in my test.js the path of options will cause an error, since my test.js is in the directory ./test/test.js, whereas app.js is in ./app.js.

I'm struggeling to find a clean solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your options into a module, you can either use it directly or stub it in your test using something like [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) or [sandboxed-module](https://github.com/felixge/node-sandboxed-module)

Alternatively you could modify your exports to accept the options as a parameter so that you require it with e.g. require('server')(config)

Comment: Wrap your server code in a closure:

function startServer(config){
  return https.createServer(options, app).listen(app.get("port"), function(){
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
}

module.exports = startServer;